# How to create deb package with build dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, build, deb

I have a package clarity-icon-theme and to build it it need ImageMagic. When I create that package launchpad throw that "convert command not found".

How can I create deb package that use ImageMagic on build time, so it can be build by launchpad demon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify ImageMagick in the `Build-Depends` field of the [control file](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#control).